# Animate triangles – rotate "roll" along all their sides

Tags: animation

I'm animating a lot of triangles. Every triangle will roll along its edge over and over again.
I have tried animating the pivot point with an empty but that method is getting too complex with many triangles.
Is there any easier way to do it?
[image: Walking triangle]

Comment: The [Animation Replicator with Offset addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVRn2SXTXGs) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use animation nodes. Here you have a simple setpup on how to animate polys changing its pivot point.

[image]

Comment: please include a blend file at least, if this is intended to make someone interested in animation nodes you can give them something that will run and show what you mean. screenshots are such a pain to try to recreate in a nodeview (especially if someone hasn't used the add-on before).

Comment: If you don't provide more info, this is practically a non-answer. (even if animation nodes is a very good solution for this)

Comment: @JorgeLosillaMartínez  Without an explanation on what the logic is behind this node tree, very few users will find this answer useful. Please add more detail to it.